# Implementing Java Classes and Code onto a webpage

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

This is my first time using java with a web page so I am completely ignorant on the matter and I apologize if I offend anyone with my coding. 
From looking over the internet I can see that if I have a class that I want to implement into a webpage I need to make sure it is compiled and put the .class file inside a classes folder inside the WEB-INF folder.

The class that I am talking about is the following code:

```
public class Transaction {
   String type;
   double amount;
   Object date;
public Transaction(double account, double amount, Object date){
    this.type = type;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.date = date;
}
public String toString(){
    String string = "Account Number: "+type+"\nAmount: "+amount+"\nDate: "+date;
    return string;
}
```

}

Now this is where I get lost I would like to have the following code work interactively with the web page:

```
ArrayList<Transaction> track = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    String amount = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("amount");
    String acountFrom = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("accountNum1"}
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
    Transaction newItem = new Transaction(accountNum1,amount,formattedDate);
    track.add(newItem);
```

What the above code is intended to do is take two variables that are from a HTML form that is sent to the page with the above code working within it. It gets a time stamp and puts it into the arraylist. What I am hoping to do once this work is get the arraylist to print out on a page to show all of the transactions taken place. Thanks again for any suggestions.

EDIT: I am using Tomcat as my server and JSTL/JSP for the functionality side of the website.

Comment: You need to look at servlets and jsp files.  Essentially you would have a form on a jsp page that would POST to a servlet.  The servlet would accept the parameters amount and accountNum1 from the request.  It would also perform the code you have posted and place any outputs as an attribute on the request.  The request would then be forwarded to a jsp to display the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need two pieces to make this work, the Web server and the HTML template you're putting the data into. Java has the Servlet API for building Web applications, but it's a very low-level API, and there are a number of frameworks that take care of the details for you. I recommend looking at [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/); it's a very easy launcher builder for applications using the Spring Framework, and you can have a working Web application in one short Java class.

You'll also need the HTML template for your data. One main option is JSP, but these days I prefer [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org), as it's easier to preview the static HTML piece in a browser while working on it. Both JSP and Thymeleaf are automatically supported by Spring Boot. Whichever you choose, you'll write and HTML page with some placeholders (usually either divs or table rows, depending on how much detail you're putting into your transactions) and pass your `List<Transaction>` to it (in Spring, you do this by adding it to the `Model`).

Comment: Im using tomcat as my server and I was thinking of JSP as that's what i've been taught with. Do I just import the class and throw the code inside some <%%> tags or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The OP hasn't seemed to grasp the concept of servlets and jsp files yet and your recommending `Spring` and `Thymeleaf`?  I never downvote but this is very tempting.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Have you actually tried Spring Boot? You can literally write one `Controller` class, slap a one-line `main` on it, and run it with `java`; Spring Boot will autoconfigure an entire servlet container, Spring context, templating environment, and whatever else (including JPA repositories if you give it database properties). IMO it's a lot more sensible to start with Spring controllers and views and then dig down into the Servlet API as necessary than to start in by hand-hacking scriptlets.

Comment: @chrylis I haven't tried Spring Boot, however I have setup Spring MVC + Spring Data + Hibernate on my own many times.  I have no issue with the technologies you recommend.  I just believe it is better to gain a basic understanding of the underlying mechanisms of these frameworks before you begin using them.  In a sense, your suggesting the OP sprints before they learn to walk.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Look at it. As long as you're not doing anything esoteric (or understand Spring well enough to identify the extension points, usually by providing either an `@Configuration` with an `@Enable*` or something implementing `*Configurer`), it will do nearly all of your setup for you, and it will mostly Do The Right Thing. I'm suggesting the OP learn to walk before he learns kinesiology.